# Chomsky Schützenberger enumeration theorem

Tags: algebra, grammars

In many textbooks the Chomsky-Schützenberger enumeration theorem is stated as that the characteristic formal power series of a language is $\mathbb N$-algebraic, if the grammar is unambigious. In some other books the formulation is given, that the structure describing function $$f_L(x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}l_nx^n$$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ iff the grammar is unambigious, where $l_n = \vert \Sigma^n \cap L \vert$.
I understand that by replacing every terminal by the same terminal in the system of equations associated with a grammar $G$ it is possible, to obtain the structure describing function, but I couldn't find a proof anywhere,(and don't know how I could construct one)  that then the (analytical) power series $f_L(x)$ is not transcendental.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a proof in the book of Kuich & Salomaa, *Semirings, Automata, Languages* and another one in the paper of Panholzer, "Gröbner Bases and the Defining Polynomial of a Context-free Grammar Generating Function", J. of Automata, Languages and Combinatorics **10** (2005), 79–97.   I wish there were a simple and clear proof of the result.

Comment: But it's called _Chomsky-Schützenberger_ enumeration theorem; shouldn't there be a proof in their _Algebraic theory of context-free languages_ (Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematic), which seems very accessible? However, I quickly looked through it but I couldn't find an explicit statement there (let alone a proof). If it isn't there, then the question rises where the name comes from...

Comment: It is named for them because they had the basic statement and idea in their paper, although they did not supply a complete formal proof.    That is not unusual in mathematics.

Comment: Oh I see, no that isn't at all uncommon. But how big is the gap between the ideas that Chomky and Schützenberger provide and the actual proof? Because from casual glancing both Kuich&Salomaa and Panholzer need quite a bit of machinery to get there (I don't know how much because there is no explicitly delineated proof in those either, as far as I can tell). How much of the Kuich-Salomaa book do you need?

Comment: The ingredient that is needed is some guarantee that when you take an unambiguous CFG and convert it to a system of algebraic equations in the almost-trivial way described by Chomsky and Schützenberger, that there indeed exists a solution to this system in power series, and that it is unique.

Comment: So what would I need to read in the Kuich-Salomaa book? I'm a logician, so this is not really my topic, but I've always wanted to learn about this proof; I remember reading that the transcendence of $\pi$ was equivalent to some language being inherently ambiguous and found that quite neat, although I'm not sure I remember the details correctly.

Comment: Not the transcendence of $\pi$ but rather the transcendence of the formal power series analogue over a finite field.  I can't tell you what to read in the book because the pandemic makes it impossible for me to access a copy currently.

Comment: Have you found access in the mean time to your copy?